# Mysql Query is slow with one where condition on Exists

Tags: mysql, sql

**I got 3 tables and the relations between them is many to many .**

[This is the Image of my tables with its columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcUIA.png)

**I need to get the hashtag names that has files with specific category_id .**

the problem is that  when i use the below query without specifying the category , it performs well like 0.05s .

```
select `hashtags`.`slug` 
from `hashtags` 
where EXISTS (
   select * from `files` 
   inner join `file_hashtags` on `files`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`file_id` 
   where `hashtags`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`hashtag_id` 
);
```

but when i perform the below query with specified category it goes like 3s to perform  .

```
select `hashtags`.`slug` 
from `hashtags` 
where EXISTS (
   select * from `files` 
   inner join `file_hashtags` on `files`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`file_id` 
   where `hashtags`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`hashtag_id` 
   and `files`.`category_id`=2 
);
```

**what can i do to improve this to get the better query time ? also i did this query using IN instead of Exists , but the result is the same with a little like 0.1s better perform in time.**

**about the indexes :**

- files table has ID as primary key , and category_id as BTREE index (need this for when i need to perform easy queries like get files with specific category) , and slug as Unique index .
- hashtags table has ID as primary key , and slug as Unique index .
- file_hashtags table has two foregin keys for their tables , also (file_id , hashtag_id) is Primary.

also there are about 150k rows in files table , 75 in hashtags table and 260k in the pivot table.

**UPDATE :**

If i use category=10  in my query it performs so fast because i got like 3k data with that category , but if i use category=2 , its so slow like 3 seconds because i got more than 90k data with that category , i hope this helps to find the problem.

Another thing is that when i use explain , it uses Primary key for files table in first query , but it using category index for files table in second query that i assume is the normal behaviour.

Comment: _"This is the Image of my tables with its columns"_ is not comprehensive enough. It's better yo post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` result into your question instead. That will show all the keys and indexes as well.

Comment: Also, you can check your query execution plan by adding `EXPLAIN` on both of your queries.

Comment: i used Explain , when there is no category in where clause , it uses PK for files table , but when there is category in where clause , it uses that which is the normal behaviour i think

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join without exist:

```
select distinct `hashtags`.`slug` 
from `hashtags`
inner join `file_hashtags` on `hashtags`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`hashtag_id`
inner join `files` on `files`.`id` = `file_hashtags`.`file_id`
where `files`.`category_id`=2
group by `hashtags`.`slug`;
```

Comment: i used this , i get 4s query time using this .

Comment: i think the query it self is not wrong in my post , but maybe a data type , index issue or something .

Comment: are you sure that category_id is indexed ?

Comment: Yea,it is index BTREE,i can see using navicat. I got like 10 categories.

Comment: What about `hashtag_id` and `file_id` are they indexed too  !!

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are redundant, don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
SELECT hashtags.slug
FROM hashtags
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * 
FROM files
WHERE category_id = 2) A
INNER JOIN file_hashtags ON A.id = file_hashtags.file_id
WHERE hashtags.id = file_hashtags.hashtag_id)
```

If the number of rows in the files table is large, the number of join records can be reduced by performing a filter before proceeding with the join operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It shows what indexes you have

I assume that `file_hashtags` is a many-to-many mapping?  Then it needs

```
PRIMARY KEY(file_id, hashtag_id)
INDEX(hashtag_id, file_id)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Because of `and files.category_id=2`, `files` needs

```
INDEX(category_id)
```

So, have those ids, and simply the query to:

```
SELECT  h.slug
    FROM  files AS f
    JOIN  file_hashtags AS fh  ON fh.file_id = f.id
    JOIN  hashtags AS h  ON h.id = fh.hashtag_id
    WHERE  f.category_id = 2;
```

(I assume `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table, though `id` is *not needed* in `file_hashtags`.)

I do not believe `EXISTS` helps with performance for this query.

*If you are not using `ENGINE=InnoDB`, my answer is inadequate.  You should be using InnoDB.*

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have any dup slugs, so I did not include `DISTINCT`.  (`DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` would slow down the query by dedupping, possibly with a temp table and sort.)

Comment: the indexes are as follows that you wrote , for example if i change the query , to use different category , it performs fast because it has low data , but with category=2 its slow because i have more than 90k data with this category

Comment: Approximately how many rows in each table?

Comment: i wrote that in the post . 
there are about 150k rows in files table , 75 in hashtags table and 260k in the pivot table.

Comment: You need 90K rows of output?  That takes time to shovel across the network to the client.  If there is more to the query, please show it.  It _does_ matter if there are more columns being `SELECTed` or more conditions in the `WHERE` or there is a `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY`.